# Really high loss/low accuracy with a LSTM using Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to understand Sequence-To-Sequence and LSTM by coding a simple text summarizer with Keras. I am using a small part of a dataset (500 articles) from the CNN news dataset. Not really sure if I am doing this correctly.

First, after an hour of running, I have an extremly high loss and low accuracy. Even if i am not training the model with a graphic card, I still think the accuracy is really low.

```
Epoch 10/10
500/500 [==============================] - 59s 117ms/step - loss: 43815452.8000 - acc: 0.0231
```

Second, now that I made the encoder, I am looking to make the decoder but I have absolutely no idea how i could generate a summary : when I look at the "predict" function, it returns an array of (500, 1748, 62) and the last dimension of the array seems to contain probabilites ?. I thought that it could be the probabilities over my vocabulary, meaning that I should pick the most likely word, but the vocabulary has 313974 words so I don't know how to interpret this output. I read a few articles where it said that you can use a second LSTM for decoding but how the two LSTM can communicate together ? Should I pass the states from the first one ?

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong and explain, that would be greatly appreciated :) .

Here is the code I use for the encoder :

```
#Some informations
#VOCAB_SIZE = 313974
#np.shape(x_train) = (500,1748) and contains index of the words 
#np.shape(word_embedding_matrix) = (313974, 300) and contains my words in a 300 dimensions space pre-processed with GloVe.

def create_model():
    prob=0.5
    EMBEDDING_DIM = 300
    VOCAB_SIZE = nb_words

    embedding_layer = Embedding( VOCAB_SIZE,
                                EMBEDDING_DIM,
                                weights=[word_embedding_matrix],
                                trainable=False)

    LAYER_NUM = 3
    HIDDEN_DIM = 300

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(embedding_layer)

    for i in range(LAYER_NUM - 1):
        model.add(LSTM(y_train.shape[1], return_sequences=True))
        model.add(Dropout(prob, name="drop_%s" %(i)))

    LSTM(y_train.shape[1], return_sequences=False)

    model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1]))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model = create_model()
y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (y_train.shape[0], 1, y_train.shape[1]))

nb_epoch = 0
while True:
    print('\n')
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=1, nb_epoch=10)
    nb_epoch += 1
```

And the summary of the model :

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_4 (Embedding)      (None, None, 300)         94192200  
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, None, 62)          90024     
_________________________________________________________________
drop_0 (Dropout)             (None, None, 62)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_7 (LSTM)                (None, None, 62)          31000     
_________________________________________________________________
drop_1 (Dropout)             (None, None, 62)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, None, 62)          3906      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, None, 62)          0         
=================================================================
Total params: 94,317,130
Trainable params: 124,930
Non-trainable params: 94,192,200
```

Comment: What is your y_train

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos y_train contains the index of the words from the summarize. In fact I'm not sure if it has the correct shape, currently (500, 1, 62). In my opinion it make more sense if it was (500,61, 1) but I have dimensions problems with the activation layer if I do that.

Comment: Some pointers: a) you can define the softmax axis, b) you do not need a dense layer on top of your decoder, c) your number of articles compared to your i/o vocabulary sizes are extremely low, d) your encoder shape is extremely low and does not need to be the same as your decoder shape. That said, I can't help you solve your problem because you're giving way too little information and it's impossible to reproduce your problem. Try providing some charts of performance, I/O examples, etc.